# Fail to install signed package with peer chaincode install command

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I follow the instruction in the following link to install signed package.
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0-beta/cc-packaging-and-signing.html

But I got the following error when execute "peer chaincode install ccpack.out".
The error message is

*Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = proto: bad wiretype for field peer.ChaincodeSpec.Type: got wiretype 2, want 0*

If I omit the -s flag in the create chaincode package step, the the raw ChaincodeDeploymentSpe can be successfully installed.

Can someone help me how to install the package with signature (i.e. with -s flag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CR pending review https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/12727/ which should fix this issue.